# FreeSWITCH replies 404 to PUBLISH

Tags: publish, sip, freeswitch

I'm connecting to FreeSWITCH with QuteCom SIP client. After a clien is successfully registered, I publish my presence by changing the status to BUSY. But FreeSWITCH replies "404 Not Found".

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 932 bytes from udp/[192.168.1.39]:5060 at 07:05:17.940940:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   PUBLISH sip:1200@192.168.1.249 SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.39:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK131644078
   From: <sip:1200@192.168.1.249>;tag=1098221491
   To: <sip:1200@192.168.1.249>
   Call-ID: 1650132002@192.168.1.39
   CSeq: 20 PUBLISH
   Contact: <sip:1200@192.168.1.39:5060>
   Max-Forwards: 70
   User-Agent: qutecom/rev-g-trunk
   Event: presence
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, OPTIONS, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, MESSAGE
   Content-Type: application/pidf+xml
   Content-Length:   452
   
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <presence xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf'
   xmlns:dm='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:data-model'
   xmlns:rpid='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid'
   xmlns:c='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:cipid'
   entity='sip:1200@192.168.1.249'>
   <tuple id='t2267e46e'>
   <status>
   <basic>closed</basic>
   </status>
   </tuple>
   <dm:person id='pdc5ba422'>
   <rpid:activities>
   <rpid:busy/>
   </rpid:activities>
   <dm:note></dm:note>
   </dm:person></presence>
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 642 bytes to udp/[192.168.1.39]:5060 at 07:05:17.943156:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 404 Not Found
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.39:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bK131644078
   From: <sip:1200@192.168.1.249>;tag=1098221491
   To: <sip:1200@192.168.1.249>;tag=H5BZvmUQ37jjB
   Call-ID: 1650132002@192.168.1.39
   CSeq: 20 PUBLISH
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.0.head-git-765908f 2011-05-22 19-10-52 -0500
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, UPDATE, INFO, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, precondition, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, presence, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Content-Length: 0
```

The presence info in publish is completely [RFC4480](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4480) conformant.

What should I configure to make PUBLISH work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to first subscribe to "presence.winfo" event.

Comment: I wish you would have told us HOW to do this. I've been looking to hours on how to subscribe to the event and still no luck.